# Doctrines automatically aborted in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am currently following the symfony-tutorials of Leanna Pelham and Ryan Weaver, and i quickly ran into some problems. I am struggling with the "doctrine:generate" commands, both entities and cruds.

This happens when I type in "php app/console doctrine:generate:entity":
[doctrine:generate:entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzP8H.png)

This happens when I type in "php app/console doctrine:generate:crud":
[doctrine:generate:crud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn6eg.png)

I have tried to google this, but couldn't find anything. First i thought a button was jammed up, and that's what caused it to automatically abort, but I am not sure. I would really appreciate if anybody could help me.

Comment: What terminal are you using? According to `Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/DialogHelper.php:131` this happens when stty isn't available and stdin cannot be read.

Comment: Okey, thank you for the answer. I am using just normal windows cmd, will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the PHP version. Just replace all the files in the directory: **C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.0**  in your development platform (I use **wampserver** in my case) with a more recent version of PHP.