# Doctrine generate entity aborted

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

When I try to execute the command

```
php bin\console doctrine:generate:entity
```

I put the name of my bundle, the type of configuration that I want, in my case yml, but at the moment of insert the name of the first attribute for the entity the console starts to out the message

```
New field name (press <return> to stop adding fields): Aborted
```

Until I don't use the combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> the console don't stop of print this message.

There is a question with the same problem here:
[Doctrines automatically aborted in Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44721325/4757412).
In that question someone says that is problem of stty and stdin but nobody explain how solve it.

Update:
In Symfony there are two functions that return a RuntimeException with the message Aborted. Both are in the QuesionHelper class. The first function is getHiddenResponse and the second is readFromInput. I suppose that the second function is returning the error but I don't know why, I have not yet been able to debug it but I think that the options are:

1. The condition of the if return false and the function fgets return false too. In this case can be that the variable $stream isn't equals to STDIN or that the function readline don't exists
2. The function readLine doesn't works.

This is the code of the readFromInput function:

```
 private function readFromInput($stream)
{
    if (STDIN === $stream && function_exists('readline')) {
        $ret = readline();
    } else {
        $ret = fgets($stream, 4096);
    }

    if (false === $ret) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Aborted');
    }

    return trim($ret);
}
```

Comment: What happen when you enter the command stty ?

Comment: And what system do you use ? Linux ? Windows ??

Comment: @SylvainAttoumani I'm using Windows10 and the stty isn't a windows command. I have tried with cygwin that simulates a linux command line and I have the same problem.

Comment: Just hit enter..